# map! isn't changing the original array

Tags: ruby

`@key` contains an array of four different three-digit integers. `someArray` has about ten three-digit ints. I have a method that has an array I'm attempting to modify. I'm using `map!` to accomplish this:

```
def multiply()
  count = 0
  @someArray.map! do |map|
    if @key[count]
      map = map * @key[count]
      count = count + 1
    else
      count = 0
      map = map * @key[count]
      count = 1
    end
  end
  print @someArray
end
```

I'm getting a few unexpected results.This prints `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2]`. Why wouldn't this print the `map * @key` value instead of the count?

Comment: You're question could be improved by including a small example of `@someArray` and `@key` and the associated desired output.  Also, choosing variable names that are also the names of methods tends to be confusing, especially when both are used in the same breath.  Lastly, it is the near universally-adopted custom in Ruby to use "snake-case" for variable names and method names (all_lower_case_and_underscores rather than dromedariusCase).

Comment: You'd often see this written `@someArray.map.with_index {|a,i| a * @key[i%@key.size]}`, but I much prefer @meagar's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` uses the return value from the block. Your return value is either `count = 1` or `count = count + 1`.

You cannot *assign* over top of the block's input variable, that has absolutely no effect.

Correctly written, your block would look something like this:

```
@someArray.map! do |i|
  if @key[count]
    i *= @key[count]
    count = count + 1
  else
    i *= @key[0]
    count = 1
  end
  i
end
```

As an aside, this is a slightly inappropriate use of `map`. There are far better ways of combining the elements of two arrays, even if one of those arrays is shorter.

Given two inputs:

```
someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
key = [2,4,6]
```

You can combine these two arrays into one array of pairs, using `.cycle` to produce an enumerator that will wrap around so that both arrays are functionally the same length:

```
pairs = someArray.zip(key.cycle)
# => [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 2], [5, 4], [6, 6], [7, 2], [8, 4], [9, 6], [0, 2]]
```

Then, you can map the resulting array, multiplying the pairs:

```
pairs.map { |a,b| a * b }
# => [2, 8, 18, 8, 20, 36, 14, 32, 54, 0]
```

So, in all, your method would be:

```
def multiply()  
  @someArray.zip(@key.cycle).map { |a,b| a * b }
end
```

Comment: So adding a return at the end of the if and else would correct this?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about zip or cycle. That is much cleaner!

Comment: That's an unusual and nifty use of `cycle` with `zip`. I can think of many uses for it. For example, a common situation is where one one wants to pass elements of an array into a block and treat those with even offsets differently than those with odd offsets. You commonly see `each_with_index` used for that, but isn't `arr.zip([:even, :odd].cycle)` so much nicer?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's going to consume well over twice as much memory to produce this array, and I consider it much harder to read than the equivalent `each_with_index`. I really wouldn't recommend this approach over `each_with_index`.

Comment: Good point. I benchmarked `arr.each_with_index.reduce(0) { |t,(e,i)| i.even? ? t : t+e}` against `enum = [:even, :odd].cycle; arr.reduce(0) { |t,e| enum.next.eql?(:even) ? t : t+e}` (yes, I dropped `zip`). For `arr = Array.new(1_000_000, 1)`, the former took 0.23 seconds, the latter, 1.20 seconds. The latter is still quite a bit slower, but acceptable for modest-size arrays.